# Align HTML form inputs in a line using css

Tags: html, css, web

I want to design HTML form like below with CSS effects. I tried a lot but getting the correct form and getting error in CSS too.

```
    <div class="row">
 <form action="search.php" method="get" name="jobsearch" id="jobsearch">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
<label>Keywords</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="job title, keywords " class="form-control"      name="keyword" value="">
 </div> 
 <div class="col-md-3"> 
   <label>Location</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter location here" class="form-control"   name="location" value="">
 </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">

<label>Select Country</label>
<select name="co" class="form-control">
            <option value="us">United States</option>
    <option value="ar">Argentina</option>
    <option value="au">Australia</option>
    <option value="in">India</option>


            </select>
            <script language="JavaScript">
                    DropDownSelect(document.jobsearch.co, 'in');
            </script>

  </div>

      <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top:25px;">
    <input id="fj" class="btn btn-primary" value="Find Jobs" type="submit">
  </div>


 </form>
```

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqPNd.png)!

Comment: Post some code what you have tried...

Comment: Could you please post your code? If you want your form elements to be in one line you should try floating the elements left.

Comment: code added... please check and provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways that you can accomplish this using CSS. I can not say that one way is better than the other without knowing the environment you are working in.

*Seeing how your style of coding is using inline CSS and padding elements i will also use these in the answer although i do not think these are always the optimal solution*

Also i believe we might be missing a closing div tag at the end of this as well.

Inline CSS styling is what accomplished this task.

float:left; //if applied to elements they will not line break inbetween them as long as they have enough space to fit on the same line.

After that it was just getting the padding correct to make the elements spaced far enough away from each other on the same line.

And carefully applying widths to each element to put the input box below the text. Also put the form width to 600px so that instead of resizing the form when the resolution changes it will add a scroll bar. (If you want this behavior to change you will have to find a solution to this).

```
 <div class="row">
     <form action="search.php" method="get" name="jobsearch" id="jobsearch" style="width:600px;">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" style="float:left;width:80px;">
             <label>Keywords</label>
                 <input type="text" placeholder="job title, keywords " class="form-control"      name="keyword" value="">
         </div> 
         <div class="col-md-3" style="float:left;width:80px;padding-left:100px;"> 
             <label>Location</label>
                 <input type="text" placeholder="enter location here" class="form-control"   name="location" value="">
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-2" style="float:left;width:100px;padding-left:100px;">

         <label>Select Country</label>
             <select name="co" class="form-control">
                 <option value="us">United States</option>
                 <option value="ar">Argentina</option>
                 <option value="au">Australia</option>
                 <option value="in">India</option>


             </select>
             <script language="JavaScript">
                    DropDownSelect(document.jobsearch.co, 'in');
             </script>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top:20px;float:left;padding-left:20px;">
            <input id="fj" class="btn btn-primary" value="Find Jobs" type="submit">
        </div>
```

Comment: thank you,but i have to insert html form below the header in www.decentjobs.in wordpress site.

Comment: Are you running into any issues with my code and inserting it into your wordpress site?

Comment: yes,error on submiting the values (using get method), i need the same look of decentjobs.in/search.php form look on .